# SQL Server Data Tools - Visual Studio 2015 Error

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015

I'm trying to install SQL Server Data Tools - Visual Studio 2015, but I keep getting errors.

Here is the log file- https://drive.google.com/file/d/1yVS6JnjekPAWCr899K8vH9NuCkmBgUjW/view?usp=sharing

```
[052C:28B4][2020-10-25T09:29:45]: Prompt for source of package: VSTASetup2015, payload: VSTASetup2015, path: C:\Users\Isuru Anuradha\Downloads\payload\x86\vsta_setup.exe
[052C:28B4][2020-10-25T09:29:45]: Acquiring package: VSTASetup2015, payload: VSTASetup2015, download from: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=817280&clcid=0x409
[06F0:2014][2020-10-25T09:30:05]: Error 0x80070490: Failed to find expected public key in certificate chain.
[06F0:2014][2020-10-25T09:30:05]: Error 0x80070490: Failed to verify expected payload against actual certificate chain.
[06F0:2014][2020-10-25T09:30:05]: Error 0x80070490: Failed to verify signature of payload: VSTASetup2015
[06F0:2014][2020-10-25T09:30:05]: Failed to verify payload: VSTASetup2015 at path: C:\ProgramData\Package Cache\.unverified\VSTASetup2015, error: 0x80070490. Deleting file.
[06F0:2014][2020-10-25T09:30:05]: Error 0x80070490: Failed to cache payload: VSTASetup2015
[052C:28B4][2020-10-25T09:30:05]: Failed to cache payload: VSTASetup2015 from working path: C:\Users\ISURUA~1\AppData\Local\Temp\{8c753f57-9344-4eea-bb4d-e9cd00768a3f}\VSTASetup2015, error: 0x80070490.
[052C:28B4][2020-10-25T09:30:05]: Application requested retry of payload: VSTASetup2015, encountered error: 0x80070490. Retrying...
[052C:28B4][2020-10-25T09:30:05]: Prompt for source of package: VSTASetup2015, payload: VSTASetup2015, path: C:\Users\Isuru Anuradha\Downloads\payload\x86\vsta_setup.exe
[052C:28B4][2020-10-25T09:30:08]: Acquiring package: VSTASetup2015, payload: VSTASetup2015, download from: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=817280&clcid=0x409
[06F0:2014][2020-10-25T09:30:20]: Error 0x80070490: Failed to find expected public key in certificate chain.
[06F0:2014][2020-10-25T09:30:20]: Error 0x80070490: Failed to verify expected payload against actual certificate chain.
[06F0:2014][2020-10-25T09:30:20]: Error 0x80070490: Failed to verify signature of payload: VSTASetup2015
[06F0:2014][2020-10-25T09:30:20]: Failed to verify payload: VSTASetup2015 at path: C:\ProgramData\Package Cache\.unverified\VSTASetup2015, error: 0x80070490. Deleting file.
[06F0:2014][2020-10-25T09:30:20]: Error 0x80070490: Failed to cache payload: VSTASetup2015
[052C:28B4][2020-10-25T09:30:20]: Failed to cache payload: VSTASetup2015 from working path: C:\Users\ISURUA~1\AppData\Local\Temp\{8c753f57-9344-4eea-bb4d-e9cd00768a3f}\VSTASetup2015, error: 0x80070490.
[052C:28B4][2020-10-25T09:30:20]: Application requested retry of payload: VSTASetup2015, encountered error: 0x80070490. Retrying...
[052C:28B4][2020-10-25T09:30:20]: Prompt for source of package: VSTASetup2015, payload: VSTASetup2015, path: C:\Users\Isuru Anuradha\Downloads\payload\x86\vsta_setup.exe
[052C:28B4][2020-10-25T09:30:23]: Acquiring package: VSTASetup2015, payload: VSTASetup2015, download from: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=817280&clcid=0x409
[06F0:2014][2020-10-25T09:30:33]: Error 0x80070490: Failed to find expected public key in certificate chain.
[06F0:2014][2020-10-25T09:30:33]: Error 0x80070490: Failed to verify expected payload against actual certificate chain.
[06F0:2014][2020-10-25T09:30:33]: Error 0x80070490: Failed to verify signature of payload: VSTASetup2015
[06F0:2014][2020-10-25T09:30:33]: Failed to verify payload: VSTASetup2015 at path: C:\ProgramData\Package Cache\.unverified\VSTASetup2015, error: 0x80070490. Deleting file.
[06F0:2014][2020-10-25T09:30:33]: Error 0x80070490: Failed to cache payload: VSTASetup2015
[052C:28B4][2020-10-25T09:30:33]: Failed to cache payload: VSTASetup2015 from working path: C:\Users\ISURUA~1\AppData\Local\Temp\{8c753f57-9344-4eea-bb4d-e9cd00768a3f}\VSTASetup2015, error: 0x80070490.
[06F0:2014][2020-10-25T09:30:33]: Removing cached package: VSTALS2015, from path: C:\ProgramData\Package Cache\4F812BBB2BE7E30CED293F8A229A5410D70DE6DB\
[06F0:2014][2020-10-25T09:30:33]: Removing cached package: SQLAMO, from path: C:\ProgramData\Package Cache\{12AC43BD-44C4-4207-82E3-B92B1D0F6F7C}v14.0.600.111\
[06F0:2014][2020-10-25T09:30:33]: Removing cached package: SQLASADOMD, from path: C:\ProgramData\Package Cache\{98D5E340-C558-4B1F-BC65-2895FB356B20}v14.0.600.111\
[06F0:2014][2020-10-25T09:30:33]: Removing cached package: SSDT14, from path: C:\ProgramData\Package Cache\{6CE5278E-3260-4E64-8B98-00D80CF7B292}v14.0.61707.300\
[06F0:2014][2020-10-25T09:30:33]: Removing cached package: SSDTEXTERNALS13, from path: C:\ProgramData\Package Cache\{CDED15B3-65CE-4DAD-A602-8F12564E688E}v13.1.4001.0\
[06F0:2014][2020-10-25T09:30:33]: Removing cached package: SQLSMO13X64, from path: C:\ProgramData\Package Cache\{D5829155-CEBE-4B91-8CDD-642942284ADC}v13.1.4001.0\
[06F0:2014][2020-10-25T09:30:33]: Removing cached package: SQLSMO13X86, from path: C:\ProgramData\Package Cache\{9C95FAAF-AC2A-45C2-A778-79FBBDD3A59A}v13.1.4001.0\
[06F0:2014][2020-10-25T09:30:33]: Removing cached package: SQLCLRTYPES14X64, from path: C:\ProgramData\Package Cache\{A825DFF0-A610-49A3-BF7C-C5772A0F488B}v14.0.800.90\
[06F0:2014][2020-10-25T09:30:33]: Removing cached package: SQLCLRTYPES14X86, from path: C:\ProgramData\Package Cache\{BB1CC3B8-7A05-4566-93D5-68C4EFF24629}v14.0.800.90\
[06F0:2014][2020-10-25T09:30:33]: Removing cached package: SQLCLRTYPES13X64, from path: C:\ProgramData\Package Cache\{1F4D6A03-93BB-4BA0-9524-DB7CA0B17B24}v13.1.4001.0\
[06F0:2014][2020-10-25T09:30:33]: Removing cached package: SQLCLRTYPES13X86, from path: C:\ProgramData\Package Cache\{9070F68A-4B84-4AFF-84C2-0BA772E71107}v13.1.4001.0\
[06F0:2014][2020-10-25T09:30:33]: Removing cached package: SQLLOCALDBX64, from path: C:\ProgramData\Package Cache\{9097BF1A-13A0-4A4A-A1F8-473E2A669863}v13.1.4001.0\
[06F0:2014][2020-10-25T09:30:33]: Removing cached package: SQLDOM13X64, from path: C:\ProgramData\Package Cache\{C78CC1C8-D0DF-4F47-BA93-F3AE6E80E047}v13.1.4001.0\
[06F0:2014][2020-10-25T09:30:33]: Removing cached package: adalsql13X64, from path: C:\ProgramData\Package Cache\{52D1FCFD-1052-4D75-B3FB-9906901AFD98}v13.1.4001.0\
[052C:1EF8][2020-10-25T09:30:33]: Error 0x80070490: Failed while caching, aborting execution.
[06F0:0D44][2020-10-25T09:30:33]: Removed bundle dependency provider: {8c753f57-9344-4eea-bb4d-e9cd00768a3f}
[06F0:0D44][2020-10-25T09:30:33]: Removing cached bundle: {8c753f57-9344-4eea-bb4d-e9cd00768a3f}, from path: C:\ProgramData\Package Cache\{8c753f57-9344-4eea-bb4d-e9cd00768a3f}\
[052C:1EF8][2020-10-25T09:30:33]: Apply complete, result: 0x80070490, restart: None, ba requested restart:  No
```

Please Help me.

Comment: Does [this previous StackOverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63473258/390122) help?

Answer (score 4):

you can download the offline ISO from the below url and install. There is some connectivity that is blocking it from downloading from the Web at the time of installation.

https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2132817

Answer (score 1):

Link for the ISO download has been changed to
https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=832317&clcid=0x409

Comment: This should've been a comment on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66570724/16019058). Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/32153098)